# Read mixed encoding string

Tags: c#, encoding

I read some string with (windows-1256) encoding but the numbers in that string encoded using (UTF-8) and as a result all text except numbers (encoded with utf-8) read but numbers displays as (?) which is acceptable. but i want to know how can i read complete text without problem, how can i know when to switch between encodings to read correct text. 
NOTE: Browsers displays these kind of text correctly so they know when they should switch

Any solution or code ?

Comment: any chance the original string would read (all of it) fine as utf8?

Comment: No i can't read windows-1256 encoded string using utf8 cause it returns wrong character displays as cube ;)
most part of the string is windows-1256 and only numbers are UTF-8, so i wonder how browser can render it successfully

Answer (score 0):

The lower half of the windows-1256 code page is the same as ASCII.  Digits in UTF-8 are also the same as ASCII - if you read the string with windows-1256 encoding, it should work just fine.

Comment: Unless they are [Eastern Arabic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) numbers.

Comment: Yes thats exactly arabic numbers and if I read them with windows-1256 that would return (?)

Comment: you are right, but arabic numbers has different ASCII code and the problem is reading UTF8 arabic number with windows-1256, i should somehow detect numbers and read them with correct encoding.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood; sorry about that.  I'm not sure mixing encodings is going to be something easy to pull apart...